# Totally offline windows phone 8 mapping application

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary

I recently developed an Android mapping app in which I used osmdroid for an offline maps API, and used tiles downloaded for offline tile sources. I've been thinking of going into WP 8 dev for a while now, and one of the things I would like to know is the same kind of thing possible WP 8.

First of all, is the maps API available in Windows Phone 8 really available offline, coming from Android where I had to use an alternative like osmdroid i have a hard(yet pleasant) time wrapping my head around this, and second which would be my alternatives for tile sourcing, remember I need those tile sources to be completely offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - if you use [Maps API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx), it is available offline if regions are downloaded with [MapDownloader task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206984(v=vs.105).aspx) (or other program already downloaded it via this Task).

As it is said [here in the blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/24/the-windows-phone-map-control.aspx):

> One of the unique features is shared offline maps and map caching. When a user downloads a region of maps for offline use through the Map Downloader included in the OS, those offline maps are also available to all consumers of the map control.
>
> All apps have access to offline maps – pretty cool! There is also something special about the APIs for geocode (address to coordinate), reverse geocode (coordinate to address), and routing. These are hybrid online/offline APIs; the platform determines whether each request should go online or use offline map data in the shared map cache.